Require at compile time that two of three optional parameters are passed to method
Say I have a method:
def foo(one: Option[String], two: Option[String], three: Option[String])

Callers must always pass to this method at least two of the three optional parameters. How can I enforce this at compile time?

Do you mean that it has = None as a default parameter, or that 2 of 3 must be Some?

With that signature that is impossible to achieve. If you add some type trickery, you may validate it using type-level programming but that is quite hard. IMHO, the best solution is to have a simple ADT that provides all the valid options.

There could be a solution but one, two and three would need all to have different types and not passed in as Option

You can check this at runtime:
def foo(one: Option[String], two: Option[String], three: Option[String]) = {
  require(Seq(one, two, three).count(_.isDefined) >= 2,
    s"at least two of $one, $two, $three must be Some"
  )
}

foo(None, None, None)
// java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: at least two of None, None, None must be Some

Generally you can't do this at compile time because it can become known whether options are None only at runtime (later than compile time).
But you can do this at compile time if it's already known at compile time whether the options are None. You can make foo a macro
// libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

def foo(strOpts: Option[String]*): Unit = macro fooImpl

def check(strOpts: Option[String]*): Unit =
  require(strOpts.count(_.isDefined) >= 2,
    s"at least two of ${strOpts.mkString(", ")} must be Some"
  )

def fooImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(strOpts: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  check(strOpts.map(tree => c.eval(c.Expr[Option[String]](c.untypecheck(tree)))): _*)
  q"()"
}

// another subproject

foo(None, None, None) // doesn't compile
// exception during macro expansion: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: at least two of None, None, None must be Some

But
val x = Some("a") // runtime value

foo(x, Some("b"), Some("c")) // doesn't compile 
// exception during macro expansion: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find proxy for val x...

The macro can be improved with traversing ASTs
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

def foo(strOpts: Option[String]*): Unit = macro fooImpl

def check(strOpts: Option[String]*): Unit =
  require(strOpts.count(_.isDefined) >= 2, s"at least two of ${strOpts.mkString(", ")} must be Some")

def fooImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(strOpts: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._

  def eval[A](t: Tree): A = c.eval(c.Expr[A](c.untypecheck(t)))

  def getRhs(t: Tree): Tree = {
    var rhs: Option[Tree] = None

    val traverser = new Traverser {
      override def traverse(tree: Tree): Unit = {
        tree match {
          case q"$_ val $_: $_ = $expr"
            if tree.symbol == t.symbol ||
              (tree.symbol.isTerm && tree.symbol.asTerm.getter == t.symbol) =>
            rhs = Some(expr)
          case _ => super.traverse(tree)
        }
      }
    }

    c.enclosingRun.units.foreach(unit => traverser.traverse(unit.body))

    rhs.getOrElse(c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"can't find $t"))
  }

  def eval1[A](t: Tree): A = util.Try(eval[A](t)).getOrElse(eval[A](getRhs(t)))

  check(strOpts.map(t => eval1[Option[String]](t)): _*)

  q"()"
}

val x = Some("a")

foo(x, Some("b"), Some("c")) // compiles
// foo(None, None, None) // doesn't compile: exception during macro expansion: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: at least two of None, None, None must be Some

But then
val x = Some("a")

val x1 = x

foo(x1, Some("b"), Some("c")) // doesn't compile: exception during macro expansion: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find proxy for val x

so the macro can be improved more, etc.
How to get the runtime value of parameter passed to a Scala macro?
Def Macro, pass parameter from a value

If I understand correctly you want to check that the input to foo is of one of the following forms:

None, Some, Some
Some, None, None
Some, Some, None
Some, Some, Some

This can be achieved with an enum like this:
sealed trait TwoOutOfThree[A, B, C] {
    def oneOpt: Option[A]
    def twoOpt: Option[B]
    def threeOpt: Option[C]
}

case class FirstNone[A, B, C](oneOpt: Option[A], two: B, three: C) extends TwoOutOfThree[A, B, C] {
    def twoOpt: Option[B] = Some(two)
    def threeOpt: Option[C] = Some(three)
}

case class SecondNone[A, B, C](one: A, twoOpt: Option[B], three: C) extends TwoOutOfThree[A, B, C] {
    def oneOpt: Option[A] = Some(one)
    def threeOpt: Option[C] = Some(three)
}

case class ThirdNone[A, B, C](one: A, two: B, threeOpt: Option[C]) extends TwoOutOfThree[A, B, C] {
    def oneOpt: Option[A] = Some(one)
    def twoOpt: Option[B] = Some(two)
}

